# How to deploy xmapp server By 2 pc 1 notebook in 1 router?

Tags: xampp, server

1. What is a  OS to deploy server ?
2. Can I use the window server or not ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Almost on any server you can deploy it.
2 - Yes you can use windows server.

Comment: Thank you. will start from the offline server What should I do.